# Splitting a string and count occurrence of components in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset in format like this in my BigQuery table:

| Keywords | Count |
| --- | --- |
| test,abc,c | 1 |
| test | 1 |
| abc | 2 |

How can I transform it to:

| Keywords | Count |
| --- | --- |
| test | 2 |
| abc | 3 |
| c | 1 |

Thanks,

Raymond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'test,abc,c' AS Keywords, 1 AS Count UNION ALL
  SELECT 'test', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', 2
)
SELECT keyword, SUM(Count) AS Count 
  FROM sample_table, UNNEST(SPLIT(Keywords)) keyword
 GROUP BY 1;
```

###### Query results

```
+---------+-------+
| keyword | Count |
+---------+-------+
| test    |     2 |
| abc     |     3 |
| c       |     1 |
+---------+-------+
```